# Call alternative method in class using postsharp

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

I want to be able to call a differnt method on my intercepted class by using `PostSharp`.

Say I have the following method in my `PostSharp` aspect:

```
    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        if (!m_featureToggle.FeatureEnabled)
        {
            base.OnInvoke(args);
        }
        else
        {
            var instance = args.Instance;
            instance.CallDifferentMethod(); //this is made up syntax
        }  
    }
```

The `CallDifferentMethod()` is another method within the class  that has been intercepted. I can do some reflection magic to get the name of what I want to be called, but I can't work out how to call that method on *this* instance of the class. I don't want to spin up a new instance of the class

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you casting args.Instace to your type? Based on what you wrote, I'd imagine that your "FeatureEnabled" should be defined through an interface.

```
public interface IHasFeature
{
  bool IsFeatureEnabled { get; set; }
  void SomeOtherMethod();
}
```

then use

```
((IHasFeature)args.Instance).SomeOtherMethod();
```

Then apply the aspect to that interface.

```
[assembly: MyApp.MyAspect(AttributeTargetTypes = "MyApp.IHasFeature")]
```

or on the interface directly

```
[MyAspect]
public interface IHasFeature
```

Update: Oops, Gael is right. Sorry about that. Use the CompileTimeValidate method to LIMIT the aspect at compile time.

```
public override bool CompileTimeValidate(System.Reflection.MethodBase method)
        {
            bool isCorrectType = (Check for correct type here)
            return isCorrectType;
        }
```

For more information, see my post http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-9-Aspect-Lifetime-Scope-Part-1.aspx

Comment: Dustin is right regarding the cast to a common interface. An alternative is to case to "dynamic". However, applying the aspect to the interface does not "limit" the aspect to this interface. It just "applies" it. Limitation should be done using CompileTimeValidate.

Comment: Oops, @GaelFraiteur is right, use CompileTimeValidate method to actually LIMIT the application to a specific type (done at compile time).